# Slider stops working after first use

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, slider

I have a Slider control inside a ScrollView (there are other elements, but those are the pertinent ones). When you "let go" of the slider (OnMouseLeftButtonUp - also works for taps), a network command is sent and the slider is momentarily greyed out. After the slider becomes available again, when I try to drag it, it will not work, and the "let go" event doesn't fire.

I have already tried setting `e.Handled` to True/False but it seems to do nothing. What would cause a Slider to stop working after it's used one time? -Or- Is there a better event I should be using to detect when the value changes on the slider *after* the user has let go of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. You can't use a Toggle Switch (from the Silverlight SDK) with a slider because one takes exclusive control of a GestureListener.

Here's the fix I used, it worked perfectly (near the bottom):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/ba8bfef3-44a2-4e63-bded-97013e38772e/

You just have to wrap your sliders in a `<Canvas>` element and insert some event handlers.

Comment: Forum URLs have changed... think you may be referring to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/ba8bfef3-44a2-4e63-bded-97013e38772e/ which has info you describe.